# Is it possible to get .NET-Remoting MarshalByRefObject work though VPN

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, tcp, .net-remoting

I have a client application that needs to access to its server though VPN. If the .NET Remoting call passes  serializable objects between server and client, everything works. However, the client app also make a remoting call that passes a MarshalByRefObject argument, this failed because the underlying TCP connection failed to make the connection back to client's.

Unfortunately I don't have control over the corporate VPN setup, and I am not familiar with how VPN works. I tested with all firewall off, but somehow the cooperate VPN network would not allow internal network connect to the external network (client machine). I guess it of make sense to block internal network connect to an external source for security reason. The VPN client in question is Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobile Client.

My questions are:

1. Is this a limitation in .NET remoting when using MarshalByRefObject?
2. If I switch to WCF, would .NET TCP Binding Duplex connection work?
3. If I can recommend something to the IT department, what should I tell them to configure their VPN (if possible)?
4. What would be the recommended practice when writing a client-server applications though VPN?

Here is a stack trace when .NET remoting trying to marshal back to the client by failed:
Note: 10.8.26.34 is my client IP Address, and 8080 is the registered for .NET Remoting TCP channel. The ME.Streets.Service.Interface.LoadScheduleHelper is the class that derived from MarshalByRefObject, which has a property call ScheduleKey that need to be marshal to the client for the data.

Exception 
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005): A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 10.8.26.34:8080
Server stack trace:
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Connect(EndPoint remoteEP)
at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.RemoteConnection.CreateNewSocket(EndPoint ipEndPoint)
at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.RemoteConnection.CreateNewSocket()
at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.SocketCache.GetSocket(String machinePortAndSid, Boolean openNew)
at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.Tcp.TcpClientTransportSink.SendRequestWithRetry(IMessage msg, ITransportHeaders requestHeaders, Stream requestStream)
at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.Tcp.TcpClientTransportSink.ProcessMessage(IMessage msg, ITransportHeaders requestHeaders, Stream requestStream, ITransportHeaders& responseHeaders, Stream& responseStream)
at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.BinaryClientFormatterSink.SyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg)
Exception rethrown
at [0]:
at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
at ME.Streets.Service.Interface.LoadScheduleHelper.get_ScheduleKey()
at ME.Streets.Service.Provider.Remoting.ServiceEndPoints.ServiceEndPoint.LoadScheduleByPrimaryKeyInChunkWorker(LoadScheduleHelper loadScheduleHelper, Boolean loadFromDev) in c:\dev\Streets\Main\Streets\ME.Streets.Service.Provider\Remoting\ServiceEndPoints\ServiceEndPoint.sch_Schedule.cs:line 634
...

Comment: Yes, it should work with WCF, you can even use HTTP via `WSDualHttpBinding`. Here's a good read: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163537.aspx

Comment: Good to know WSDualHttpBinding works, but based on the current application design, I am hoping that netTcpBinding's callback would work in though VPN.